# Is it possible to specify timeline attachment as a reference

Tags: google-mirror-api

Is it possible to specify timeline attachment reference. I don't want to resend the same video, is there a way of bundling timeline item with previously send timeline item, so that it can be played without any delay. or Does "update timelineitem" do the same?

Answer (score 1):

No, not right now, but this is a highly requested feature that we're actively working on.

We're tracking it [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=26), on the official issue tracker. If you star the issue, you'll be notified once it's updated (for example, when we close the issue as fixed).